# Need help on While loop in Python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a really simple game using python.

The game is snake ladder where the player goes from start to finish (0 - 100)

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep

board = ["1" ,"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11" ,"12", "13", "14", "15",
     "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21" ,"22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29",
     "30", "31" ,"32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41" ,"42", "43",
     "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51" ,"52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57",
     "58", "59", "60", "61" ,"62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71",
     "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81" ,"82", "83", "84", "85",
     "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91" ,"92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99",
     "100"]

def print_board(board):
    print ("   ".join(board[0:10]))    #first row
    print ("   ".join(board[10:20]))    #second row
    print ("   ".join(board[20:30]))    #third row
    print ("   ".join(board[30:40]))    #fourth row
    print ("   ".join(board[40:50]))    #fifth row
    print ("   ".join(board[50:60]))    #six row
    print ("   ".join(board[60:70]))    #seventh row
    print ("   ".join(board[70:80]))    #eight row
    print ("   ".join(board[80:90]))    #ninth row
    print ("   ".join(board[90:100]))    #tenth row


dice = randint(1, 6)   #random number 1 - 6
def roll_dice(dice):       #function to roll the dice
    print ("Rolling the dice...")
    sleep(1.5)
    print ("..."), dice
    return


player_score = 0    #starting point / score

def player(player_score):    #for Information
    print ("You are now at %d") % player_score

def main():                          #game starts
    print ("Let's play a game")
    while player_score < 100:        #This is the problem, the while doesn't recognize player_score
        print_board(board)
        player_choice = input("put R for Rolling or I for Information: ")
        player_choice = player_choice.upper() 
        if player_choice == "R":
            roll_dice(dice)
            if dice == 1:
                player_score = player_score + 1
                print ("Player moves.. ")
                player(player_score)     
            elif dice == 2:
                player_score = player_score + 2
                print ("Player moves.. ")
                player(player_score)
            elif dice == 3:
                player_score = player_score + 3
                print ("Player moves.. ")
                player(player_score)
            elif dice == 4:
                player_score = player_score + 4
                print ("Player moves.. ")
                player(player_score)
            elif dice == 5:
                player_score = player_score + 5
                print ("Player moves.. ")
                player(player_score)
            elif dice == 6:
                player_score = player_score + 6
                print ("Player moves.. ")
                player(player_score)
        elif player_choice == "I":
            player(player_score)
    else:
        print ("Congratulations, you won the game!")
```

But the problem is, the loop doesn't even start. it says:

> "local variable 'player_score' referenced before assignment".

Also: How can i continue the game to the player_choice again with the player_score already added?

Answer (score 0):

define  your variable player_score = 0  inside main

```
def main(): 
    player_score = 0                         #game starts
    print ("Let's play a game")
    while player_score < 100:        #This is the problem, the while doesn't recognize player_score
        print_board(board)
        player_choice = input("put R for Rolling or I for Information: ")
        player_choice = player_choice.upper() 
        if player_choice == "R":
            roll_dice(dice)
            if dice == 1:
                player_score = player_score + 1
                print ("Player moves.. ")
                player(player_score)     
            elif dice == 2:
                player_score = player_score + 2
                print ("Player moves.. ")
                player(player_score)
            elif dice == 3:
                player_score = player_score + 3
                print ("Player moves.. ")
                player(player_score)
            elif dice == 4:
                player_score = player_score + 4
                print ("Player moves.. ")
                player(player_score)
            elif dice == 5:
                player_score = player_score + 5
                print ("Player moves.. ")
                player(player_score)
            elif dice == 6:
                player_score = player_score + 6
                print ("Player moves.. ")
                player(player_score)
        elif player_choice == "I":
            player(player_score)
    else:
        print ("Congratulations, you won the game!")
```

And the end of game you can again request from user to run again the game. if he accept then again call your method from your start your game

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! can i ask one more thing. Now that the game runs, the dice doesn't roll a random number each time. it always stuck at the same number. what's wrong with it ?

Comment: define the numbers also in a function where you rolling the dice.
 if above answer is correct please accept the answer that this is correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
def print_board(board):
    print ("   ".join(board[0:11]))    #first row
    print ("   ".join(board[11:20]))    #second row
    print ("   ".join(board[21:30]))    #third row
    print ("   ".join(board[31:40]))    #fourth row
    print ("   ".join(board[41:50]))    #fifth row
    print ("   ".join(board[51:60]))    #six row
    print ("   ".join(board[61:70]))    #seventh row
    print ("   ".join(board[71:80]))    #eight row
    print ("   ".join(board[81:90]))    #ninth row
    print ("   ".join(board[91:100])) 

def roll_dice(): #function to roll the dice
    dice = randint(1, 6)
    print ("Rolling the dice...")
    sleep(1.5)
    print ("..."), dice
    return dice
 #game starts
def main():
    player_score = 0

    print ("Let's play a game")
    while player_score < 100:
        print_board(board)
        player_choice = raw_input("put R for Rolling or I for Information: ")
        player_choice = player_choice.upper()
        if player_choice == "R":
            dice = roll_dice()
            if dice == 1:
                player_score = player_score + 1
                print "Player moves.. ", dice
            elif dice == 2:
                player_score = player_score +  2
                print "Player moves.. ", dice
            elif dice == 3:
                player_score = player_score + 3
                print "Player moves.. ", dice
            elif dice == 4:
                player_score = player_score + 4
                print "Player moves.. ", dice
            elif dice == 5:
                player_score = player_score + 5
                print "Player moves..",dice

            elif dice == 6:
                player_score = player_score + 6
                print "Player moves..", dice

            print "You are now at %d" % player_score
    elif player_choice == "I":
        print "You are now at %d" % player_score
else:
    print ("Congratulations, you won the game!")
```

The reason you see `raw_input()` is because `input()` gives an error that R is  not defined and the reason you see a slight change in indexing is because your code generates some numbers twice
And you see that there is no player function because there is only  one command